# FPS Timer Not Working

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm creating a game in Visual studio 2015 with c++ and sdl-2, I'm currently implementing an fps timer but it's not working. The basic FPS Timer code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <Camera.h>

int main()
{

//create objects + camera

float frameTime = 0.0f;
int prevTime = 0;
int currentTime = 0;
float deltaTime = 0.0f;

    while (isRunning)
    {

    SDL_Event ev;

    keyState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

    prevTime = currentTime;
    currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
    deltaTime = (currentTime - prevTime) / 1000.0f;

    frameTime += deltaTime;

        if (frameTime >= 0.25f)
        {

            if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_W] && !FreeRoam)
            {
                Object1.GetPos().z = (Object2.GetPos().z + 1);
                camera.MoveForward(1);
            }
            //render
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

The FPS Timer in question is ripped straight from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRpen8jOa08) video by CodingMadeEasy. The problem is the fps timer acts as though it is non-existent, so how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Next learn about `<chrono>` to handle your timing needs in a type-safe fashion.  Type-safety means that careless errors such as confusing time points with time durations are caught at compile time.  Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your code. You are counting the time between two lines:

```
prevTime = currentTime;
currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
deltaTime = (currentTime - prevTime) / 1000.0f;
```

This doesn't make any sense. You want the time between two loop's iterations, so you have to split these lines in the bounds of the loop:

```
while (isRunning)
{
    prevTime = currentTime; // Right here, in the loop's beguining

    SDL_Event ev;

    keyState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

    if (frameTime >= 0.25f)
    {

        if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_W] && !FreeRoam)
        {
            Object1.GetPos().z = (Object2.GetPos().z + 1);
            camera.MoveForward(1);
        }
        //render
    }

    //End of the loop

    currentTime = SDL_GetTicks();
    deltaTime = (currentTime - prevTime) / 1000.0f;

    frameTime += deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: upvoted, thanks for solving the problem and explaining your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't reset frameTime to 0 after frame update.

Comment: For future readers:  This is the correct answer.  The currently accepted answer doesn't change the OP's logic, and repeats the bug this answer points out.